# Get the interface name from the implementation class

Tags: java, class, interface

Example :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//This would give me the class name for the list reference variable.
list.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

I want to get the Interface name from the `list` reference variable. 
Is there any way possible to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using Reflection you can invoke the [`Class.getInterfaces()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces%28%29) method which returns an `Array of Interfaces` that your class implements.

```
list.getClass().getInterfaces()[0];
```

To get just the name

```
list.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName();
```

Comment: You may also want to recurse on the interfaces extended by these interfaces.

Comment: @Guillaume good point, they would be class implementing order, for instance interface[0] would be java.util.List and interface[1] would be java.util.RandomAccess

Comment: And if you want to get the Collection interface you have to call getInterface() on the interfaces returned by the first call.

Answer (score 2):

```
Class  aClass = ... //obtain Class object. 
Class[] interfaces = aClass.getInterfaces();
```